# Create new table without any formatting

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I have an issue with creating table from file that I download from server/database. It's an older .xls file. In that file there is a list with 67 columns and arbitrary number of rows (it depends on how much data there is). When I select list and create table from it, formating is applied which changes the default formating of the list. I go to `Disign > Table Styles` and click `clear` but that does not clear all formatting that is applied; new column width stays.

I need column width not to change when I create table, or any other formating that might be applied. This really mess up my files and renders them useless for later usage. I need to create table without any formatting applied. Im using Excel 2016/1808/32bit on Windows 7/64bit.

Thanks xD

Comment: When you apply a table style, local formatting is preserved by default. Can you give an example of what you are doing?

Comment: Just create 2x2 list with text in first 2 rows and numbers in second 2 rows. Text needs to be longer than column length(lets say 20 characters.). When you create table from that list column width will change to the length of the text. That column length stays even when you click `clear` in Design tab.

Comment: I think when you create a table from data the column width auto-resizes to the greater of the default width (64 pixels on my current computer) or the header length (plus some padding so the selection filter arrow doesn't block the header). To resize you'll probably need VBA that reads the column widths, store them in an array, then apply the table, then resize the columns to the widths in your array.

Comment: @gns100 Any of stopping it in the first place xD.

Comment: suppressing the default behavior is beyond me (as evidenced by my response to workaround the default behavior). Maybe if you poked around how a table is created, you could find the part that does the column resize and override it with VBA. Then you would run that program instead of clicking on the table button...

Comment: @IGRACH, better you share some sample data along with any Format if applied, before convert into TABLE. Also, While reject Table Format would you like to keep Filter Buttons or not ?

Answer (score 1):

**This VBA (Macro) will help you to create TABLE without any Format and Filter buttons.**

```
Sub TableWithoutStryle()
Dim Trange As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set Trange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Please select a range,,", _
                    Title:="Create Table", Type:=8)


Ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Trange, , xlYes).Name = "NewTable1"
   Ws.ListObjects("NewTable1").TableStyle = ""
    Ws.ListObjects("NewTable1").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Press **ALT+F11** to open VB editor.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this Code as **Standard 
  Module** with the Sheet.
- Run the Macro & Select required Data Range you 
  want to convert into *TABLE*, as soon **INPUT 
  Box** appears.
- Finish with **Ok**
- You Find Selected Data Range now converted into *TABLE* without any Format, (Check using Table Design Command).

**N.B.**

*In above Code `Sheet & Table name` are editable.*

Comment: When I run this; it changes column width.

Comment: @IGRACH,, not possible this code doesn't have any command to change the width!! Get ready with data,, RUN the Macro,, while INPUT Box appears, select the data,, finish with Ok,,You get the Table!! I've tested this code before I've posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I added code to capture column widths and restore them after inserting the table:

```
Sub TableWithoutStryle()
Dim Trange As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim ColWidth()

Set Ws = ActiveSheet

Set Trange = Selection

NumCols = Trange.Columns.Count

ReDim ColWidth(NumCols)

For i = 1 To NumCols
    ColWidth(i) = Trange(1, i).ColumnWidth
Next i

Ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Trange, , xlYes).Name = "NewTable1"
   Ws.ListObjects("NewTable1").TableStyle = ""
    Ws.ListObjects("NewTable1").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    
For i = 1 To NumCols
    Trange(1, i).ColumnWidth = ColWidth(i)
Next i

End Sub
```